# Using Apple Extended Keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard

So Ive searched apple support and googled a bit but any solution Ive come across is either outdated 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D31uzS1Szek

or assumes you are using OSX with a Bootcamp partition.

I am running Windows 10 and have purchased a Apple extended keyboard but have lost all access to things like single and double quotes etc.

What can I do to regain full use of my keyboard (cant type a question mark since I get É instead :)

Answer (score 0):

> (cant type a question mark since I get É instead :)

It seems that your keyboard layout has changed. In Windows 10, you can select your preferred keyboard by doing these steps:

1. Open the Settings app (<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>)
2. Click on *Time & Language*
3. Click on *Region & Language*
4. Select your language
5. Click *Options*
6. Finally, select everything under *Keyboard* except *US* and click on *Remove*.

**Note**: If the *US* Keyboard is not in the list, you can add it.